# Pyspark Transpose

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data in the below format with 38 measure columns for various months as shown below.

```
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+------+------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+------------------+
| Cust_No | Measure1_month1 | Measure1_month2 | .... | Measure1_month72 | Measure2_month_1 | Measure2_month_2 | ….so on | Measure2_month72 |....Measure38_month1...
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+------+------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+------------------+
|       1 |              10 |              20 | ….   |              500 |               40 |               50 | …       |                  |
|       2 |              20 |              40 | ….   |              800 |               70 |              150 | …       |                  |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+------+------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+------------------+
```

I want to achieve the below format using PYSPARK.

```
+---------+-------+----------+----------+
| CustNum | Month | Measure1 | Measure2.......measure38 |
+---------+-------+----------+----------+
|       1 |     1 |       10 |       30 |
|       1 |     2 |       20 |       40 |
|       1 |     3 |       30 |       80 |
|       1 |     4 |       70 |       90 |
|       1 |     5 |       40 |      100 |
|       . |     . |        . |        . |
|       . |     . |        . |        . |
|       1 |    72 |      700 |       50 |
+---------+-------+----------+----------+
```

and so on for every customer number

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need `wide to long` kind of transformation which can be achieved by `stack` in pyspark

I created a sample dataframe with 5 months data

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,10,20,30,40,50,10,20,30,40,50),(2,10,20,30,40,50,10,20,30,40,50)],['cust','Measrue1_month1','Measrue1_month2','Measrue1_month3','Measrue1_month4','Measrue1_month5','Measrue2_month1','Measrue2_month2','Measrue2_month3','Measrue2_month4','Measrue2_month5'])
```

Now generating the clause for stack operation. Can be done in better ways but here is the most simplest example

```
Measure1 = [i for i in df.columns if i.startswith('Measrue1')]
Measure2 = [i for i in df.columns if i.startswith('Measrue2')]
final = []
for i in Measure1:
    for j in Measure2:
        if(i.split('_')[1]==j.split('_')[1]):
            final.append((i,j))
rows = len(final)
values = ','.join([f"'{i.split('_')[1]}',{i},{j}" for i,j in final])
```

Now actually applying the stack operation

```
df.select('cust',expr(f'''stack({rows},{values})''').alias('Month','Measure1','Measure2')).show()

+----+------+--------+--------+
|cust| Month|Measure1|Measure2|
+----+------+--------+--------+
|   1|month1|      10|      10|
|   1|month2|      20|      20|
|   1|month3|      30|      30|
|   1|month4|      40|      40|
|   1|month5|      50|      50|
|   2|month1|      10|      10|
|   2|month2|      20|      20|
|   2|month3|      30|      30|
|   2|month4|      40|      40|
|   2|month5|      50|      50|
+----+------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, Thanks for your response. The table that I am using has 2500+ columns(Measures), so I am not sure I can use the looping logic that you used in your code. Can it be modified so that it can take all the columns together and create the dataframe?