# pandas pivot_table (slow) vs pyspark pivot

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am trying to perform a pivot_table operation on pandas on a file that is 40GB in size.

This takes a lot of time to run(1.5 hours). I am doing this on a hadoop cluster by converting the spark dataframe into pandas and using pyarrow. But using pandas, I believe this operation is running on that particular node only. And at the end I am converting it into a spark dataframe again.

Input:

```
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+------+------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+------------------+
| uniqueid | Measure1_month1 | Measure1_month2 | .... | Measure1_month72 | Measure2_month_1 | Measure2_month_2 | ….so on | Measure2_month72 |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+------+------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+------------------+
|       1 |              10 |              20 | ….   |              500 |               40 |               50 | …       |                  |
|       2 |              20 |              40 | ….   |              800 |               70 |              150 | …       |                  |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+------+------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+------------------+
```

Output:

```
+---------+-------+----------+----------+
| uniqueid| Month | Measure1 | Measure2 |
+---------+-------+----------+----------+
|       1 |     1 |       10 |       30 |
|       1 |     2 |       20 |       40 |
|       1 |     3 |       30 |       80 |
|       1 |     4 |       70 |       90 |
|       1 |     5 |       40 |      100 |
|       . |     . |        . |        . |
|       . |     . |        . |        . |
|       1 |    72 |      700 |       50 |
+---------+-------+----------+----------+
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
    df_input = spark.sql("select * from inputtable")
    
    df_input_pd=df_input.toPandas()
    
    d = df_input_pd.set_index('uniqueid')
    d.columns = d.columns.str.replace('m\_', 'm').str.split('_', expand=True)
    u = d.stack((0, 1)).rename_axis(
          ['uniqueid', 'Measure', 'Month']).to_frame('Value').reset_index()
    f2 = u.pivot_table(index=['uniqueid', 'Month'], columns='Measure', values='Value', fill_value=0).sort_values(['uniqueid', 'Month'])
    
    
    spDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(f2)
    spDF.write.insertInto("outputtable",overwrite=False)
```

f2(pivot) and insertinto are the operation that takes the maximum time. Is there any way to optimize it by using pyspark pivot or any other operation? I tested this on a smaller set of data and it works fine. Is there a more optimum way to do this? Please let me know if something is not clear. Thanks again

Regards,
Sawan

Answer (score 0):

stay away from pandas and use spark `pivot` function:

```
df.pivot('Measure')
```

*Post a sample of the data and what you're expecting your end result to look like.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My data input and output looks like in the link below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64144812/pyspark-transpose/64150034#64150034

there are 2500+ columns and it is a 40 GB file.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated here. Thanks!

Comment: Currently, tied up at work, will take a look when I get a chance. Maybe start a bounty to get more exposure.

Comment: Thank you Jay for the suggestion